# Using localstorage with a selection list and a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have this portion of a plugin I wrote that lets a player select a consumable item from a drop down list and how many they would like to use. Recently it was requested that the selections they make would still be there when they return to the page later. This sounds like a job for localstorage! The problem is that when the user returns and the value is correctly set by localstorage it doesn't set the value of ConsumableNUM normally set by the onchange event.

Here is the current selection list and button

```
<input type="button" class="btnFJ" value="Energy" onclick="ACTIONS.use_consumable(EnergyCons,ConsumableNUM)">
<form style="display: inline">
<SELECT class="FJselect" name="numberconsumables" style="width: 54px" id="FJsconsumables" onchange="ConsumableNUM = this.options[selectedIndex].value;">
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" selected value="1">1</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="2">2</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="3">3</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="4">4</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="5">5</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="6">6</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="7">7</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="8">8</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="9">9</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="10">10</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="11">11</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="12">12</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="13">13</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="14">14</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="15">15</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="16">16</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="17">17</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="18">18</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="19">19</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="20">20</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="21">21</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="22">22</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="23">23</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="24">24</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="25">25</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="26">26</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="27">27</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="28">28</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="29">29</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="30">30</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="50">50</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="100">100</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="500">500</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</form>
```

and here is the setting of localstorage that recalls the previously selected value.

```
document.getElementById("FJsconsumables").onchange = function() {
localStorage.setItem('FJsconsumables', document.getElementById("FJsconsumables").value);
}
if (localStorage.getItem('FJsconsumables')) {
document.getElementById("FJsconsumables").options[localStorage.getItem('FJsconsumables')].selected = true;
}
```

Thanks!

***EDIT***

Not sure why but, when I try to apply the same method to a a second selection list it isn't working. It is either not saving the value or sometimes returning the wrong one! The second list and the function for it is below:

```
<form style="display: inline">
<SELECT class="FJselect" name="typeofconsumables" style="width: 110px" id="FJConsumable">
<option>-Energy</option>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1b" value="1">Energy Drink - 10</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1b" value="5">Energy Infusion - 20</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1b" value="9">Atomic Energizer</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1b" value="11">Nucleic Reaction - 50</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1b" value="609">NUCLEIC ENERGY - 50</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1b" value="234">Red Line - 55</OPTION>

<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="523">SHC Present - 155</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="489">Hallow Skull  - 160</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="499">Red Eyeball  - 203</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG1" value="501">Blue Eyeball  - 203</OPTION>
<OPTION class="FJoptionBG2" value="503">Yellow Eyeball  - 203</OPTION>
</select>
```

and the function:

```
document.getElementById("FJConsumable").onchange = function() {
localStorage.setItem('FJConsumable', document.getElementById("FJConsumable").value);
}
if (localStorage.getItem('FJConsumable')) {
document.getElementById("FJConsumable").options[localStorage.getItem('FJConsumable')].selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Do you set the selection after the select is available in the DOM? The shown script in your document's head won't work.

Comment: The script was based on this jsfiddle someone had posted in another thread - http://jsfiddle.net/Lyxut/6/

Comment: It DOES recall the previously selected value when a user returns.

Comment: but, when I try to use the button it complains that ConsumableNUM is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an option as selected doesn't trigger your onchange handler. This is why your global variable is not defined. Set a value explicitly:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('FJsconsumables')) {
  document.getElementById("FJsconsumables").options[localStorage.getItem('FJsconsumables')].selected = true;
  ConsumableNUM = localStorage.getItem('FJsconsumables');
} else {
  ConsumableNUM = "1"; // or whatever is a usefull default value here
}
```

To your second question: You have an option without a value there, this could make the difference. Try to drop it to make sure.

Comment: Hmmm... still returning ConsumableNUM as not defined.  :(

Comment: I think I've got it! By dropping the use of ConsumableNUM and instead using localStorage.getItem('FJsconsumables') in it's place everything seems happy! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Any reason why the same method wouldn't work for another selection on the same page? The other piece of the button's function is list of named items with numeric values.

Comment: I added my guess for your second question. However, after the code given in my answer `ConsumableNUM` cannot be undefined. You should check the order of your Javascripts and when they are executed.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I tried that hoping it would work but, no dice. I've marked your original answer as the solution though as it got the initial set working and actually got me to revisit the code and realize I didn't need to do it with the extra ConsumableNUM variable.

Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Does the second list need to be handled differently because it's not a simply value list that goes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc? The values in the second list are the ID numbers for specific items in the game so they can't just be a regular list. How do I capture the value of them correctly in localstorage? Does the document.getElementById("FJConsumable").value part need to be written differently?

Comment: Here is the version that finally worked for the second selection list. 

`document.getElementById("FJsconsumabletype").onchange = function() { var FJC=document.getElementById("FJsconsumabletype").selectedIndex; localStorage.setItem('FJsconsumabletype', FJC); } if (localStorage.getItem('FJsconsumabletype')) { document.getElementById("FJsconsumabletype").options[localStorage.getItem('FJsc‌​onsumabletype')].selected = true; }`